# inline posts with scroling

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

My problem is i want to make this post in one line and scroling on the x and the y hidden

My html

```
<div id='related-post'>
<div class='relhead'>
<h5><span>أنميات أخرى</span></h5>
<div class='clear'/>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'      
<script expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + 
&quot;?
alt=json-in-script&amp;amp;callback=relpostimgcuplik&amp;amp&quot;' 
type='text/javascript'/>
</b:loop>
<ul id='related-summary'>
<script type='text/javascript'>relatedscript();</script>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

My css`

```
#related-post  { display : inline-block; font-family: 'jsbold'; font-size: 
14px;  padding-bottom: 7px; border-bottom: 4px solid $(main.color); line-
height: 18px; font-weight: 700; color: #111; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

My java script

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
//Related Post
var relnojudul = 0;
var relmaxtampil = 8;
var numchars = 90;
var reljudul=new Array();var relurls=new Array();var relcuplikan=new Array();var relgambar=new Array();function saringtags(g,h){var e=g.split("<");for(var f=0;f<e.length;f++){if(e[f].indexOf(">")!=-1){e[f]=e[f].substring(e[f].indexOf(">")+1,e[f].length)}}e=e.join("");e=e.substring(0,h-1);return e}function relpostimgcuplik(h){for(var e=0;e<h.feed.entry.length;e++){var g=h.feed.entry[e];reljudul[relnojudul]=g.title.$t;postcontent="";if("content" in g){postcontent=g.content.$t}else{if("summary" in g){postcontent=g.summary.$t}}relcuplikan[relnojudul]=saringtags(postcontent,numchars);if("media$thumbnail" in g){postimg=g.media$thumbnail.url}else{postimg="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-htG7vy9vIAA/Tp0KrMUdoWI/AAAAAAAABAU/e7XkFtErqsU/s1600/grey.GIF"}relgambar[relnojudul]=postimg;for(var f=0;f<g.link.length;f++){if(g.link[f].rel=="alternate"){relurls[relnojudul]=g.link[f].href;break}}relnojudul++}}function contains(a,e){for(var f=0;f<a.length;f++){if(a[f]==e){return true}}return false}function relatedscript(){var v=new Array(0);var w=new Array(0);var x=new Array(0);var A=new Array(0);for(var u=0;u<relurls.length;u++){if(!contains(v,relurls[u])){v.length+=1;v[v.length-1]=relurls[u];w.length+=1;w[w.length-1]=reljudul[u];x.length+=1;x[x.length-1]=relcuplikan[u];A.length+=1;A[A.length-1]=relgambar[u]}}reljudul=w;relurls=v;relcuplikan=x;relgambar=A;for(var u=0;u<reljudul.length;u++){var B=Math.floor((reljudul.length-1)*Math.random());var i=reljudul[u];var s=relurls[u];var y=relcuplikan[u];var C=relgambar[u];reljudul[u]=reljudul[B];relurls[u]=relurls[B];relcuplikan[u]=relcuplikan[B];relgambar[u]=relgambar[B];reljudul[B]=i;relurls[B]=s;relcuplikan[B]=y;relgambar[B]=C}var r=0;var D=Math.floor((reljudul.length-1)*Math.random());var z=D;var q;var t=document.URL;while(r<relmaxtampil){if(relurls[D]!=t){q="<li class='news-title clearfix'>";q+="<a href='"+relurls[D]+"' rel='nofollow' target='_top' title='"+reljudul[D]+"'><div class='overlayb'></div><img src='"+relgambar[D]+"' /></a>";q+="<a class='relinkjdulx' href='"+relurls[D]+"' target='_top'>"+reljudul[D]+"</a>";q+="<span class='news-text'>"+relcuplikan[D]+"</span>";q+="</li>";document.write(q);r++;if(r==relmaxtampil){break}}if(D<reljudul.length-1){D++}else{D=0}if(D==z){break}}};
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of confused on what you're asking. This can probably be done with just CSS. Can you use inspect element and copy the code it produces when the page is loaded or paste a link to your page where the script is being used so I could take a look.

From what I think you're asking you could try doing something like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container-inner">
<div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {width:100%}
.container-inner {width:200%}
.item{float:left}
```

Just make sure your inner container is wider than your outer container and that should give you the scrolling effect you're looking for. Hope this helps